# Using an array of parameters to generate modules

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have a `module` which stores a bitmap of different characters, that I am planning on using to display text on a matrix. Currently, the bitmap is populated with a memory initialization file, and this file is passed in as a `parameter` (I have confirmed this working in Quartus and ModelSim).

In order to actually have a lookup table for all the characters, I wanted to make a separate `module` which has instantiations of the all bitmaps, and selects the correct one based on a character code. These bitmap instantiations are created in a `generate` block, and they take the correct filename from an array. However, ModelSim doesn't like this. My code is as follows:

```
module mem_char_disp_lib(
    output logic pixel,
    input logic [4:0] x,
    input logic [5:0] y,
    input logic [6:0] code,
    input logic clk
);
    localparam CHAR_NUM = 26;
    logic [CHAR_NUM-1:0] alphabet;

    const var [CHAR_NUM-1:0] BITMAPS = {
        "/mem/char/A.hex",
        "/mem/char/B.hex",
        "/mem/char/C.hex",
        // ... a lot more declarations here...
        "/mem/char/X.hex",
        "/mem/char/Y.hex",
        "/mem/char/Z.hex"
    };

    genvar i;
    generate
        for (i=0; i<CHAR_NUM; i=i+1) begin : mem_char_disp_blocks
            mem_char_disp #(.BITMAP(BITMAPS[i])) block (
                .pixel(alphabet[i]),
                .x, .y, .clk,
                .code(i),
                .data(1'b0),
                .write_en(1'b0)
            );
        end
    endgenerate

    always_comb
        pixel = alphabet[code];

endmodule
```

The error ModelSim is giving me is:
`The expression for a parameter actual associated with the parameter name ('BITMAP') for the module instance ('block') must be constant.`
(referring to the line inside the `for` loop)

I am not sure why this doesn't work. On a hardware level, it seems like I'm just making a lot of copies of a module, and slightly tweaking each one with a constant parameter known at compile-time. Is there some basic syntax that I'm missing?

---

**Edit:** I have also tried the following code, which seems to give a runtime error:

```
for (i=0; i<CHAR_NUM; i=i+1) begin : mem_char_disp_blocks
    parameter [CHAR_NUM-1:0] BITMAPS = {
        "/mem/char/A.hex",
        // more elements...
        "/mem/char/Z.hex"
    };
    mem_char_disp #(.BITMAP(BITMAPS[i])) block (
        .pixel(alphabet[i]),
        .x, .y, .clk,
        .code(i),
        .data(1'b0),
        .write_en(1'b0) );
end
```

The error is `Module parameter 'BITMAP' not found for override.` (One of these errors for each of the generated modules; `CHAR_NUM` total.) This doesn't make sense to me, since instantiating a single one directly works just fine (e.g. `mem_char_disp #(.BITMAP("/mem/char/A.hex") block /* ... */`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `const` variable is not a constant - it is a write-once variable that gets initialized at runtime when the variable gets allocated. You need to us a `parameter` or `localparam` to assign to another parameter as you discovered in your update. You also need to fix the dimensions of the array

```
parameter bit [1:15*8] BITMAPS[26] = {
        "/mem/char/A.hex",   // 15 8-bit chars
        // more elements...
        "/mem/char/Z.hex" // 26 elements
    };
```

Can't help you with your last error without seeing the declaration of the module `mem_char_disp`

Comment: It turns out the problem with the second error was with my compilation script; the testbenches in the `mem_char_disp` module were working but they weren't in the `mem_char_disp_lib` module. Thank you!